# rspec - checking keys in hash after method call

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following method

```
def calculate_gpa
  # method code
end
```

In my tests I have the following:

```
s = Student.new

# some tests

describe "#calculate_gpa" do
  grades = s.calculate_gpa
  it "must add final_grade key/value pair to student hash" do
    grades.each do |grade|
      expect(grade.keys).to include('final_grade')
      expect(grade.values).not_to include(nil)
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that the line to test the keys fails with the actual result containing all the hash keys apart from `final_grade`. When I run call the method in irb then print the keys `final_grade` is there.

I can't figure out if my rspec syntax is wrong or my logic so any help would be greatly appreciated. I should note that I'm using ruby only, no rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would really help if you post your `Student` code.

However, you should be using `let` in this situation:

```
let(:grades) { s.calculate_gpa }
```

Comment: I was about to post my full code when I thought I try this change first and it worked! Thank yo so much, I accept your answer as soon as SO lets me.